# Could Match.start(0) ever return -1 in Python?

Tags: python, regex, python-re

I recently came across a code block using Python's [`re` library](https://docs.python.org/3.11/library/re.html#) that had a confusing sanity check.

```
import re

def someFunctionName(pattern, string):
    for match in re.finditer(pattern, string):
        match_offset = match.start(0)
        if match_offset == -1:
            raise IndexError("Capture group offset was -1.")
```

The [documentation for `Match.start([group])`](https://docs.python.org/3.11/library/re.html#re.Match.start) says it will return `-1` if the specified group exists but did not contribute to the match. The documentation also says that a group of zero will refer to the entire matched substring. I can't think of any scenario where a match could exist without a matched substring, making the `-1` check seem unnecessary.

Is there any scenario in which `Match.start(0)` could possibly return `-1`?